# Parsing RSS resources without any output

Tags: python, xml, rss

This might be a really beginner question but I dont get an error so I dont know whats going on.

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time


cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

def main():
    with open('word_list.txt') as f:
        word_list = f.readlines()

    try:
        pages = open('rss_sources.txt').readlines()
        for rss_resource in pages:
            sourceCode = opener.open(rss_resource).read()
        #print sourceCode

        try:
            titles = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>', sourceCode)

            for title in titles:
                if any(word.lower() in title.lower() for word in word_list):
                    print title

        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

main()
```

My example RSS sources are:

http://www.finanzen.de/news/feed
http://www.welt.de/wirtschaft/?service=Rss

Issues: The first RSS source is fine and it will print me out the titles that contain the keywords from word_list.txt. Now once I add the second RSS source to the .txt file my output is nothing, there is no errormessage or anything. Not even the first rss resource gives me anything.

Is there a problem with the second resource? How would I handle that error? And why isnt the first resource parsed correctly?

Please point me in the right direction so I can take care of this :)

Comment: In the for loop where you call `opener.open`, you overwrite the previous `sourceCode` every iteration without saving it anywhere. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: No, thats certainly not the way I want it. Its exactly the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to parse XML data using regular expressions. Use a well-known library, like [`feedparser`](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/common-rss-elements.html).

With that said, the problem is that you are overriding the `sourceCode` variable in your for-loop such that it only uses the last value. Indent the `try..except` block that does the title parsing so it's inside the for-loop, and it should work.

Comment: Okay thanks. I understand the point. Now I need to understand my code better to do what you said, ill figure it out eventually. Atleast now I know what the deal is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) instead of `urllib`? Also, I recommend parsing the XML document generated by the RSS resources using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it eases the process of extracting and identifying the content enclosed by each of the tags present in your document. For instance, your code could be written as:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://www.welt.de/wirtschaft/?service=Rss')
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
titles = [t.text for t in soup.find_all('title')]
for title in titles:
    #There goes your processing...
```

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with these modules aswell. But this is not the problem ;)